# Determining the connections to Mongo

Tags: mongodb, database

In Oracle, I can use V$SESSION to determine all the connections which are coming to an Oracle server. Is there any similar command for Mongo as well ? 
Is there any way to determine the number of connections ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is the [`db.serverStatus()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.serverStatus/) command and specifically you can issue just the "key" value to get the connections output:

```js
 > db.serverStatus().connections
 { "current" : 4, "available" : 15996, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(116) }
```

There are quite a lot of metrics you can get from this command. Also see the ["serverStatus"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/) database command for the full output explanation.

Comment: Thanks Neil, Is there anyway to get the machine name as well ? From where the connection is coming ?

Comment: @SrivatsaN I'm pretty sure that information is not kept in statistics but is only logged at present. Best approach is to raise a JIRA if you believe this sort of thing is important for your ongoing operations

Comment: Thank you, Have logged one, here it is https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14321